# Galeria com PHP e Javascript não funcionando corretamente

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho uma função em `JavaScript` que monta uma galeria de imagens. Tinha essa função toda em `Javascript` e funcionava perfeitamente, agora eu preciso inserir o `PHP` para que o usuário possa fazer alterações nas imagens, e estou passando o parametro para essa função através do resultado da `query` em `PHP`. Ela deveria funcionar desta maneira: Titulo da galeria em cima, e abaixo 4 imagens diferentes do resultado da `query`. Abaixo outro titulo, e outras imagens. O problema é que `PHP` está passando o mesmo parametro para a função, fazendo com a função retorne: Titulo da galeria e abaixo 4 imagens identicas(o primeiro valor da `query`), Outro titulo da galeria e outras imagens identicas(o segundo valor da `query`). Como posso fazer para que a galeria carregue 4 imagens diferentes em uma galeria, e não 4 imagens iguais em diferentes galerias ?

Minha função em `JS` está assim:

```
function galerias(query){
    var galeria = new Array();
        //aqui eu pego a div que armazena as galerias
        var imgs = document.querySelector("#gallery");
        var x = 1;

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        //passo o valor da query para o array galeria
        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = query;
        }

        e insiro dentro da div
        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+query+"'class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a class='row' href='pics.html?gal="+x+"'><div class='twelve columns link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
        x++;

}
```

Minha função em php:

```
function consultarDados($query){
    $dbResult = array();
    $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
    mysql_select_db($this->banco, $conexao);
    $rs = mysql_query($query, $conexao);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            array_push($dbResult, $rows);
        }
    return $dbResult;
    mysql_close($conexao);
}
```

Insiro este php no `window.onload` da página:

```
<?php
    foreach($galeria_1 as $result){
        echo'galerias("'.$result['nome'].'");';
    }
?>
```

O resultado visual é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e deveria ser este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica se este array ($galeria_1) tem realmente todas as posições, por que parece que ele só tem uma posição.

Comment: Sim, ele tem todas as posições !

Comment: Qual o resultado da variável $result ?

Comment: $result['nome'] retorna os valores da coluna do meu banco de dados: foto1_1.jpg foto1_2.jpg foto1_3.jpg foto1_4.jpg, e apenas o $result retorna Array Array Array Array... está parte está perfeita, aparentemente

Comment: Então ai é que está o erro meu amigo,  perceba que não função galerias você recebe "query" que era pra ser um array e não um nome de umas das imagens, por que no decorrer da função você faz um for para montar as imagens passando "query" como nome da imagem no "src" mas essa "query" é um único valor que você passou em "echo'galerias("'.$result['nome'].'");';" 
Não sei se deu pra você entender bem.

Comment: Na verdade deu sim ! Mas como eu poderia passar o array como parametro para a função...?

Comment: Cria um Json!!!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta !

Comment: De nada, estamos aqui uns para ajudar os outros!
Forte abraço meu amigo.